# React/Javascript Button onClick not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been working on a discord clone for the past few weeks [on codesandbox](https://pgcm5.csb.app/servers/default), and now I am trying to implement different servers. I have a function that takes the user's servers and creates a button for each of them, but the button onClick event does not work. I tried using `document.createElement("button")` and then attaching an event listener, but that didn't work. Then I switched to using a react element, but it still doesn't work. Am I missing something? Below is the code that handles the serverButtons.

```js
class mainFunctions {
  constructor(uInfo) {
    this.uInfo = uInfo;
  }
  setServers(servers) {
    var servBar = document.getElementById("serverIcons");
    var out = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < servers.length; i++) {
      const btn = <ServerButton id={servers[i]} key={servers[i]} />;
      out[i] = btn;
    }
    ReactDOM.render(out, servBar);
    servBar.innerHTML += `<hr class="serverBreak" />`;
  }
}

class ServerButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.id = props.id;
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    console.log("this is:", this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button
        className="serverIcon"
        id={this.id}
        key={this.id}
        onClick={this.handleClick}
      >
        C
      </button>
    );
  }
}

(new mainFunctions).setServers([1,2])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="serverIcons"/>
```

On the code sandbox, you need to sign in (using Firebase's Google Auth) and then the buttons will appear at the top of the sidebar. Thanks for your time

Comment: try adding this `onClick={() => this.handleClick()}`

Comment: This line `servBar.innerHTML += \`<hr class="serverBreak" />\`;` is breaking it. If you remove it it works.

Comment: @BrianThompson Thank you so much, I have been staring at it for the past day trying to fix it. Would the solution be to add it to the end of servers or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Well I'm not sure if you're use-case is something I've never seen, or if you're overcomplicating it, but The whole `mainFunctions` class seems unnecessary and could be leading to more confusion. When using React, you should really never have a need to manipulate the DOM manually (`innerHTML`, `createElement`, etc,). Instead make a wrapper component and use JSX for everything (including the `hr` tag).

Comment: you coud just `const out = servers.map(s => <ServerButton id={s} key={s} />)` also

Comment: The project started off modifying some code that I had from 4 years ago where I was just using manual manipulation. I just got back into js a few weeks ago so react is new to me and I was reluctant to use it when my previous method had worked in the past. The mainFunctions class is exported to my firebase handling script so when something happens on the firebase side the functions can be called. TL;DR I am almost 100% overcomplicating it

Comment: you should not manipulate dom manually in React, because React generates the DOM and handles all of it. use jsx and logic instead. also stop using Class components even React itself doesn't want some one to use them, use Functional components and hooks instead.

Comment: @SirHectorin Where have you seen React recommend against using Class components? They still use them in the documentation, as well as for the [official tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html). My opinion is that they're easier to learn with, and you can then graduate onto hooks after solidifying the core concepts of React.

Comment: @BrianThompson there is no need of publicly say "we encourage not to use class components" all they have to do is put more effort developing hooks than improving class components by more than 5 releases. even in the "Zero bundle size announcement" they didn't even mention Class components, all demo were Functional components. the conclusion is that react is leaving Class components behind gradually.